# Interesting bootstrap "modal" behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am facing interestingly weird behaviour of bootstrap "Modal" in my rails application. I have witnessed this previously, but never cared to dig. But as i face it again, i HAD to. After hours of  digging, i came to know the cause, but don't how to troubleshoot it and why is it happening.

**Scenario**:
Simple, I have a link and when its clicked, modal appears. When i change the content of body of the modal, sometimes the link is not clickable... After hours of head banging.. when i inspected using chrome dev tools, i found that the "Modal" which was hiding before the link is clicked is overshadowing the clickable link also.

Now i want to know how to troubleshoot it and know why is it blocking the link when its hiding ?

**Code:**

```
<%= link_to "All Group", '#', :data => {:toggle => 'modal', :target => '#AdminMessageAll'} %> </li>

<div class="modal fade" id="AdminMessageAll" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Send Message (to all group) </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="height:300px; width:300px">
        <%= render 'group_message_all' %>       
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <p class = "btn btn-info" > Close </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the heck are you using a `<p>` for your btn?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for this.

Comment: @cvrebert, i dint notice that , do you that could be the cause ?

Comment: I also, seen that in bootstrap , its mentioned to put modal code at the top of our code, but still nothing changed.